# Smart vs. Dumb Components - Uniform Styling

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, components, styling

I'm reviewing the concept of Smart vs. Dumb Components, and overall I think it's a good design principal. But the aspect of styling begs some obvious questions for me - The principal recommends smart components don't provide any styling, but if this is strictly adhered to, where only dumb components provide styling, wouldn't the app *look* disjoint/ununiform? Does the guideline have any say on global stylesheets?

Comment: You don't need to adhere to such principal. If adding styling to your smart components works then by all mean do it. It can be smart and pretty at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to think of Smart and dumb components having nothing to do with styling and stylesheets, even though that is how the explanation you read explained it. Think of smart and dumb components only as far as the HTML and javascript go (no CSS).

Now, your dumb components should contain only enough javascript/react code in order to work in your app. The dumb components' [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is to control the HTML composition, or presentation, of the component. This is why some people call it a [presentation component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

To continue keeping things simple: your smart components should do everything else that is related to that specific component, and the specific responsibility of that component, that is not related to the actual HTML of that component. This includes things like:

- Mapping state to the properties of the presentation component
- Mapping action dispatchers to the properties of the presentation component
- Creating any custom state, event handlers, or other muck.
- Other business logic for the component that is needed to get it to respond and interact appropriately
- Whatever other code is needed to ensure that a proper 'viewModel', or finite set of properties, is passed to the presentation component in order for that presentational component to display and function correctly.

To summarize, we should have business logic in one file (smart components) that generate a single object (props) that is passed to their HTML template counterpart (dumb component) in order to render a fully functioning component.

> **Smart components** -- Do stuff to and with various things and stuff. Generate a viewmodel/props object and pass it to dumb component.
>
> **Dumb components** -- Render html with object passed from smart component.

This is not the only way, only the way that I've been thinking about things. I hope it helps!